# Using Flask, how does the Logout Button call the logout function?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am using Python Flask to build a website. I can login, but not log out. The logout button does not respond when I click it.

The logout function:

```
@bp.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('userName')
    return redirect(url_for('index.html'))
```

The code for the logout button:
`<button type="button">Logout</button>`

The logout button is in the file ...\sent\templates\base.html
The logout function is in the file ...\sent\blueprints\auth.py

Do I need an onclick handler to call the Python function?
Do I need to import the function since it is in another directory?
Or could it be something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign an onclick handler to the button, you'd need to write the Javascrpt to send an AJAX request, and do something with the response.  However that route is performing a redirect, instead of returning JSON, so probably better just direct the user to the `/logout` URL.  For this, use an anchor tag instead of a button:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a>
```

If you want to make this appear as an actual button, then you could still style it as so.

For example, with the [bootstrap CSS library](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/buttons/) you could simply assign the relevant classes to that anchor:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Why does a button work for login and register but not logout? Is it because those are used in forms and logout is a stand alone feature?

Comment: @thejdah Yeah, those buttons will probably look more like `<input type='submit' value='Login' />` (also appears visually as a button).  Placed within a form, they cause the form to submit.  A standalone `<button>` needs some Javascript to make it do something.

Comment: Could I create a form and only put the logout button in it?

Comment: @thejdah Yeah.  You'd probably get away with`<form action="{{url_for('logout')}}"><input type="submit" value="Logout" /></form>`.  Without a `method` attrib in that form tag, it defaults to GET.