# Calling python function without form tag

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I would like to use logout list item in my navbar to use as action flask logout function. Didnt find a way either with < li> nor < a> in documentation, is it possible?

```
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="{{ url_for('food') }}">New Food Item</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="{{ url_for('view') }}">Check date</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="{{ url_for('set_up') }}">Calorie setup</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="{{ url_for('index') }} action="/logout">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

```
@app.route("/logout", methods=["GET","POST"])
def logout():
        logout_user()
        return render_template("login.html")
```

Comment: couldn't you just set it as the `url_for` instead of the `action`?

Answer (score 1):

An `action` attribute on an `li` element doesn't make sense. You can use a link as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63541838/5774952):

```
<li class="active"><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
```

Your `href` was pointing to the index, your action is pointing to logout, and you're rendering the login template in your Flask route, so you'd need to decide which you want: render the login template or redirect to the index after hitting logout.